# jQuery create text box when pressing enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to write logic in JavaScript using jQuery so that every time a user is inside of a text box and hits the enter key, a new text box is created inside the text boxes parent. The logic works on the first text box, but when I go to one of the text boxes that hitting enter on the first text box created, hitting enter in that text box does not create a new one. Any ideas how I could fix this? Thanks!

```
<div class = "wrapper">
<div class = "box" id = "box1">
<input class = "ti"  id = "t1" type="text"  placeholder= "Enter to do" >
<button  id = 'b1' type="button" onclick = "breakTheseDown()">Ok Lets Break These              
Down</button>
</div>
</div>

<script>
$( ".ti" ).on( "keydown", function( event) {
$( "#log" ).html( event.type + ": " +  event.which );
if (event.which == '13') {
    var id = event.target.id;
$("#" + id).parent().append("<input class = 'ti'  id = 't1' type='text'  placeholder=      
'Enter to do' >");
}
});</script>
```

Comment: which jquery version you are using????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event handler only binds to existing elements on the page. So using event delegation, you can bind to an ancestor element but apply to its children. Change your event handler like so:

```
$( document.body ).on( "keydown", ".ti", function( event) {
    // your function as is
});
```

Comment: This is the way to go and since he answered first i'll give him the upvote :) I would however use what HOBA suggested below and delegate to the container.

Comment: I was working on your question when I saw it answered by cyk, I made a codepen of your question working as you asked in http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xLKDd though I think probably @SebasSBM solution may be better as it is not cluttering the document body. Tnanks cyk for teaching me a new way to bind events!

Comment: Kudos to @Ihab Khattab for pointing out the performance implications of binding to distant ancestors.

Answer (score 0):

```
var i = 1;
$('#box1').on('keyup', '.ti', function(e){
    if (e.which == '13'){
        $(this).parent().find('button:last').before('<input type="text" class="ti" id="t'+ (++i) +'" placeholder="Enter to do">');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the newly created *.t1* didn't exist when you first binded your events "they weren't attached to DOM yet"

This is solved using event delegation; to bind your events to parent element that's already existed.

you can use it like

```
$( "#box1" ).on( "click", "tr", function() {
  // ...
});
```

You can also use *document* or *body* as the parent of *t1* but this isn't recommended for performance http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-performance

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    function initEvents() {
        $( ".ti" ).on( "keydown", enterFunction);
    }

    function enterFunction(event) {
        $( "#log" ).html( event.type + ": " +  event.which );
        if (event.which == '13') {
            var id = event.target.id;
            $("#" + id).parent().append("<input class = 'ti'  id = 't1' type='text' placeholder= 'Enter to do' >");
            initEvents();
        }
    }
    $(document).ready(initEvents);        
</script>
```

Well, I used to solve this problem this way, but the solution above seems much better. I'll have to check it out.

Comment: Not wrong and probably the way I'd do this natively but jquery delegation syntax is so nice why not use it :)

Comment: Because I just didn't know... :P

Comment: Well there is also the problem that if you run this multiple times since you arn't actually deleting prior events on the .ti elements this will create duplicate events. You can see this if you hit enter multiple times on the original box..makes 1 -> 3 -> etc etc Preferred method would be to pass in the element created I think and just attach the event to that element upon creation.

Comment: That explains some weird stuff that it's happening to the page I'm creating right now. Good to know. Thank you :)